# Coin with the same obverse and reverse

Tags: single-word-requests

What a coin with the same obverse and reverse face called? I found [mule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mule_(coin)) for a coin minted with obverse and reverse designs not normally seen on the same piece. But this is not what I am looking for. This question came to my mind after watching Only Angels Have Wings in which there is a coin with two heads. I found they are called two headed coin but I don't know if it is the right phrase for such a coin and of course it is not a single word.

Answer (score 4):

The term used in numismatics appears to be

> double-sided (heads or tails) coin.

They are referred to also as *double/two-headed/tailed coins.*

[image] (Amazon.com)

[How Much is a Two-Headed Coin Worth](https://www.thesprucecrafts.com/two-headed-coin-value-768399)